# Converting multiple data types on reading .csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, type-conversion, user-defined-functions

### Problem

Cleaning sales data.
Prices and quantities refuse to properly convert to either float or integer dtypes.

[example file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HLmj.png)

### Attempts

```
1. Converter function that removes "$" and ","
    Result = error message: "cannot convert string to float "" "

2. pd.to_numeric() but upon checking column via print(df['price'])
    Result = *supposedly* converts dtype to float but printing result of column returns "NaN" for all entries
```

### Expectations

Expecting the dtype in the series to be converted to "float" so that math functions may be performed on the columns. Float columns = ['Price', 'Credit Qty', 'Credit Total']

Before running my script, I ran a check on the price column and noticed my last two rows contain NaN. (Yes, I acknowledge my script coerces errors). Please also note, the last row always contains a text string of applied filters because the  .csv data is downloaded from PowerBi dashboards.

My overall goal is to accomplish all required conversions within my read_csv() argument.

### CODE

```
    def convert_currency(val):
        new_val = val.replace(',','').replace('$', '')
        return float(new_val)

    df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", na_values = [''],
               dtype={'Price': convert_currency,
                      'Credit Qty': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce', downcast = "float"),
                      'Credit Total': convert_currency)
                         })
    df.dtypes
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what filename.csv can be expected to look like?

Comment: It's too late to fix this after importing into pandas.  If it finds values in a column that don't fit, it converts the whole column to "object".  You should fix up the CSV first, then import it clean.

Comment: @Galo do Leste - I attached a picture of my example file.

Comment: @Tim Roberts - Unfortunately, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Data can range anywhere from ten to hundreds to thousands and tens of thousands of lines.

Comment: Please don't post (links to) images, make a small sample which contains the essential features, and provide it within code fences as text (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)).

Comment: I don't understand why you're using the `dtypes` argument? Try the `converters` instead, for example `converters = {"Price": lambda s: float(s.lstrip("$").replace(",", ""))}` with `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", converters=converters, on_bad_lines="skip")`. Or fix the resp. columns afterwards, for example `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", on_bad_lines="skip")` and then `df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"\$|,", "", regex=True).astype("float")`.

Comment: Thank you @Timus! Your second suggestion worked like a charm. I tried converters = converters but still received the error message, "cannot convert string to float "" "